# Design Check with Design Automation for Revit - Live Example Does not work

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

I set up the live example of the Revit Design Check on my Autodesk Hub.

Link Here: https://revitdesigncheck.herokuapp.com/

After uploading the example model, it never created an issue.

does the live example still work? Or has the older api used in the live example been deprecated?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That was indeed a problem, wrong Activity name (probably from old deploy), thanks for bringing this up. It's now fixed, and it created the issue as expected (see image)

[image]

Comment: Yes. I just did an upload and this seems to work now!

Thanks!